# Building and Deploying to Android Emulator and Android Device Coursera

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Cheers

I am following the Coursera course, but at the moment of executing the following instruction:

`ionic cordova build android`

It gives me the following error:

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME = / Users / ***** / Library / Android / sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).

I'm working on a Mac: capitan

In advance thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found for Mac

Download the Gradle Binary Only Distribution from https://gradle.org/gradle-download/

Open a terminal
Run the following to unzip the android sdk to the Development directory that is under your user home directory

unzip ~/Downloads/gradle-3.1-bin.zip -d ~/Development
Open up the vi editor and edit your bash profile. We need to add in the GRADLE_HOME environment variable

vi ~/.bash_profile
To edit in vi hit i to enter edit mode and add the text below to the .bash_profile

export GRADLE_HOME=~/Development/gradle-3.1/bin
Press the esc key to exit edit mode
Press : (colon key) to enter command mode.
type wq and press enter to save and exit vi
Run the following to make the change active in your existing session

source ~/.bash_profile
Test it by running

echo $GRADLE_HOME

source: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11591